# MVC Project taking longer to launch with every launch

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on a MVC project and the launch time increases with every launch even if I barely changed anything. Also, I am getting tons of lines in the debug console:

```
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\Launcher.vshost.exe', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x1a7c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1d64) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x1a5c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\Launcher.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\CServices.dll'
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\CommonLogger.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\ConfigurationManagerInterface.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\NLog.dll'
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\System.IO.Abstractions.dll'
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\CCBus.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Messaging\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Messaging.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\ExtractTransformLoad\bin\Debug\ETL.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\ERPCore.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\Inventory.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\InventoryInterface.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\ERPInterface.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\AutoMapper.dll'
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.dll'
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\AutoMapper.Net4.dll'
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Launcher\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Mickael\Maestria\ERP\Inventory\bin\Debug\Inventory.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Channels\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Channels.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.dll'
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll'
'Launcher.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\11.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\WebDev.WebHost40\v4.0_11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\WebDev.WebHost40.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WebMatrix.WebData\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WebMatrix.WebData.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\ee943c2a\986e1056_41f4cf01\Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\6ebbb4af\8815225c_41f4cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\b0ad0af7\f7b20256_41f4cf01\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1664) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1574) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x88c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\4be6e154\7c62f85a_41f4cf01\Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime\v4.0_1.3.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread '<No Name>' (0x18e4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x19a8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1b44) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xe70) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Razor.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\00b4944c\87417a5f_41f4cf01\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WebMatrix.Data\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WebMatrix.Data.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\App_global.asax.-ntsmtsh.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\9f5d48d2\26ff30f1_72f7cf01\WebUI.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\8e53e7c1\16475f11_6bf7cf01\System.Web.Http.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\5ef2410c\c25c2f11_6bf7cf01\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\4352827b\97985455_41f4cf01\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\348c9303\eb2c3b5a_41f4cf01\CommonLogger.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\ef9df309\2a05325a_41f4cf01\NLog.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\9061ed08\ab1f385a_41f4cf01\System.IO.Abstractions.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\89248f7d\a3457e24_6bf7cf01\InventoryInterface.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\b5ec1d90\36d97461_41f4cf01\AutoMapper.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\22bdf008\7d4a2511_6bf7cf01\Infrastructure.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\9e154841\50ae6c58_41f4cf01\EntityFramework.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\8dc28408\96527361_41f4cf01\AutoMapper.Net4.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\71ee0074\6963a570_42f4cf01\ERPInterface.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Dynamic\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Dynamic.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\App_Web_xli4na0n.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\App_Web_shtzkhkb.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\App_Web_fw2rtt2u.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\f3cc286a\a2c10a24_6bf7cf01\ERPCore.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\41096ae6\1a093ff1_72f7cf01\WebUI.resources.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\55ee94c3\18e8126f\assembly\dl3\fb7fc6fd\0b39dc58_41f4cf01\WebGrease.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml.Hosting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Xaml.Hosting.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

I tried deleting all breakpoints like it was suggested on similar posts, without success.

Comment: There seems to be a number of exceptions. Exceptions take time to evaluate and raise. Try to fix them.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Almost every line is taking a long time.

Comment: You mean executing or debugging?

Comment: When I press on start... I'm not sure if it's debugging or executing. The solution configuration is on Debug mode rather than Release mode.

Comment: Slow processor? Not enough ram?

Comment: It took less than 10 seconds to launch the first time, it takes nearly 2 minutes now even though the project's size barely increased. It can't be ram or processor. Additionally, a colleague of mine (who isn't here now) did something that reset the starting time to 10 seconds but it would increase again with every launches.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specifics on how MVC launches but I do know how the Fusion Loader works which is usually a fast thing.  However, I did notice myself when coming from desktop application work to MVC work that the wait time on loading a project into debug mode are ridiculously longer than desktop applications!  Suffice it to say that the Fusion loader is only doing what it is told to do via the assembly references.

As far as getting slower and slower, I found, that ensuring that IIS instance from previous session truly all the way down is best way to go.  You can actually compile and attempt a new debug session faster than the previous IIS session can go down.  It's almost as if you can catch it on the way down, but some how it resurrects.  IIS and VS are not totally in sync with each other.

Try this, right click on Hidden Icons and first take down all IIS instances (right click and stop), then start debug session and end, but this time watch how long it takes IIS to go down.  That is the approximate time you should wait before starting another debug session.  Sounds crazy but for me it worked well.  Keep in mind that any changes to HTML do no require restart, just save the changes and click refresh in browser. (That helped me a lot when styling up MVC pages).

Another trick I learned when developing CSHTML pages is to rename them to HTML while you are trying to style them up as VS IDE will show the styling, (Without having to run the pages).

Finally, trying to understand all of those modules being loaded is probably a good idea.  It seems that (to me anyway) that web based applications are chock full of nonsense when using JavaScript, and Jquery libiraries as well as C# libraries.  But how does one pair them down to make it all lean and mean?  I think the answer is you have to study each one to really know why it's there.